# Reading/writing raw data in Matlab

Tags: matlab, raw-data

I have a raw.txt file which is like this:

```
#   Angle   Data A       DATA B     ...       
1   45    1440.352365   3.619902121
2   45    1440.352365   3.619902121
3   45    1440.192496   3.632952692
1   45    1440.192496   3.632952692
2   45    1440.192496   3.632952692
3   45    1440.192496   3.632952692
4   45    1440.192496   3.632952692
.
.
.
```

first row(#) is repeating itself after 3. it should go to 4, 5, 6... i want to write a script that changes only that row and leave the rest like it is. i was writing something like this but getting error which i am unable to figure our

```
   function TrailRestFix(filename)

infile = fopen(filename, 'r');
outfile = fopen(filename, 'w');
i = 0;
while ~feof(infile)
    line = fgets(infile);
    space_idx = strfind(line, ' ');
    if i == 0
        fprintf(outfile,'%s',line);
    else
        fprintf(outfile,'%i %s',i,line(space_idx(1)+1:end));
    end
    i = i + 1;
end
fclose(infile);
fclose(outfile);

end
```

Comment: Could you post an example of the expected output?

Comment: Could you post the error you are receiving as well?

Comment: I want my data to output like this:

    #   Angle   Data A       DATA B     ...       
    1   45    1440.352365   3.619902121
    2   45    1440.352365   3.619902121
    3   45    1440.192496   3.632952692
    4   45    1440.192496   3.632952692
    5   45    1440.192496   3.632952692
    6   45    1440.192496   3.632952692
    7   45    1440.192496   3.632952692
    .
    .
    .  and my data is represent in data: [19810x15 double] matrix. how can i do it using matrix? and textdata: {1x15 cell} colheaders: {1x15 cell}